# IntelliJ IDEA: Jump to interface implementation if there is only one implementation available

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have a project where everything is done through interfaces. In most of the cases these interfaces have only one implementation.

**Q:** Is there a way to setup IntelliJ IDEA to automatically jump to a method implementation if there is only one implementation to the interface that I am navigating to?

**Example:**

```
MyServiceInterface service = ...;
service.doWork();
```

I want to navigate directly to `doWork()` implementation when I click on it.

Comment: Right Click -> Go to -> Implementation

Comment: In which circumstance? If you use `Ctrl+Alt+Click` on the usage of an interface method it jumps to concrete implementation (might depend on the keymap you are using)

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Click on `doWork()` should take you to the concrete implementation as I said. If there is more than one it will ask you which one you want to see

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta please post an answer. I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

Place Cursor on the `interface` and pressing `Ctrl + Alt + B` navigate to the implementation directly If only 1  implementation is available.

Comment: I am sorry, the question wasn't clear enough. Added an example.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota place cursor on the method `doWork()`  and press  `Ctrl + Alt + B`

Comment: Also, you can navigate to the only implementation using by Ctrl + Alt + mouse-normal-click(for Mac: Cmd key + option + mouse-normal-click).